# Unity object does not move straight line smoothly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have boxes generate by `Instantiate` with `Quaternion.identity` the name is **A B C D E** with the same size, next to each other and there are no spaces.
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/guD8r.jpg

There is a sphere on top of those 5 boxes that have gravity mode enabled. When the sphere moves in a straight line on boxes from A to E, sometimes it does not move smoothly at these **X** point in *image*.
I can't understand why and how to fix it.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++) spawnPath();

public void spawnPath()
{
    currentBox = Instantiate(box,currentBox.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).position,
       Quaternion.identity);
}
```

position: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8vfp.jpg

## Update:

Position: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnVZI.jpg
Note that these boxes are lined up perfectly.

Shpere movement:

`public Rigidbody rb;
void FixedUpdate(){
     rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
}`

Comment: can you share you code here.

Comment: @thirteen4054 I think that's helpless, I added code.

Comment: I think adding your movement script would be more relevant to your problem

Comment: @YingYoh add the relevant snippet.

Comment: I updated code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons this could be caused. One would be that the boxes aren't placed correctly.
Looking at your code it would generate the boxes on top of each other because the position is the same for every iteration.

In the case that the boxes line up perfectly it's also possible that this is caused due to discrete collision detection. Discrete only resolves the collision after it moved. This means that when gravity updates it might notice the collision with one of the corners and resolve it incorrectly.

Comment: The boxes are lined up perfectly. When I set collision detection as continuous, sometimes it move smoothly. The others don't